# Why did I get an error when running migration, I tried to change typedatas text to JSONB (PosgreesSql+sequelize)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I got an error when I was running a migration in sequelize,
before I set typedatas text and i tried to change to json I got some error...

`ERROR: column "value" cannot be cast automatically to type jsonb`

This is the new code:

```
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => Promise.resolve()
    .then(async () => {
      await queryInterface.changeColumn('Action', 'value', {
        type: Sequelize.JSONB,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: {},
      })
    }),
```

and this is my migration code that I want to change:

```
 up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => queryInterface.createTable('Action', {
    ....
    value: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '',
    },
    ....
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Does the column contain valid JSON? If so, `type: \`${Sequelize.JSONB} using value::jsonb\`` might work (see https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2471).

Comment: thanks , based your code i change to 
`${Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.JSONB)} USING CAST ("value" as  ${Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.JSONB)}`
its work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple solution...
i change to

```
type: 'JSONB USING CAST ("value" as JSONB)'`
```

as in https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2471

solved my problem ...

Answer (score 3):

the accepted answer doesn't work for me.

I use this one and it works.

```
type: `${Sequelize.JSONB} using to_jsonb(col_name)`
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for us. Though the data doesn't get transformed to jsonb. Do you know how to do that?